# For which integers $n$ are there solutions to the equation $x^2-y^2=n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For which integers $n$ are there solutions to the equation $x^2-y^2=n$

I believe $n$ must be divisible by $3$, since for any integers $x,y$ mod $3$. $x^2=3k+1$ and $y^2=3n+1$, thus $x^2-y^2=3(n-r)$.

Then I would have $n=0$ with $x,y=0$.

I also found that $n$ if it is even must be divisible by a power of $2$ greater then $1$. Since if $n$ is even then one of $(x+y),(x-y)$ is even, so both are even. Then $4\mid n$.

I'm not sure if there are more restrictions, or how to determine if there are no more. Assuming these are done correctly.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning regarding the divisibility by three is quite correct: $3^2 - 2^2 = ?$. In fact, what's the difference between any successive squares?

Comment: Also, how about the difference between squares of values $2$ apart, e.g, $(y+2)^2 - y^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(m+1)^2-m^2=2m+1$ gives us all positive odd $n$, eg $1=1^2-0^2,3=2^2-1^2$.

$(m+2)^2-m^2=4(m+1)$ gives us all positive multiples of 4.

$m^2-m^2=0$ and swapping $x,y$ gives us negative odd numbers and negative multiples of 4.

Any square is 0 or 1 mod 4. So we cannot have $x^2-y^2=2\bmod4$.

Comment: It's a great answer, but one small point is that there's no stated requirement that any of $x$, $y$ or $n$ be non-negative or positive. Thus, for your first two lines, $m$ could also be negative, so they give all *odd* $n$ and *all* multiples of $4$ (including $0$), respectively. Thus, your third line of swapping to get negative values would then not be required.

Answer (score 0):

As $x+y+x-y=2x,$

$x+y,x-y$ have the same parity

If both are odd, $(x+y)(x-y)=n$

we can choose $x+y=n, x-y=1$

If both are even $4|n,n=4m$ $$\dfrac{x+y}2=m,\dfrac{x-y}2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer (based on above comments) is $n$ is either odd or $n$ is even and $\frac n 2$ is odd.